# Convert network Lidar data to LaserScan

Tags: slam, navigation, hector, scan, network

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there!

I am trying to stream data back from my Parrot AR Drone 2.0, which has a LIDAR attached, to my PC (which has ROS running) in order to run Hector Slam.

I currently have code running on the quad which is reading the Lidar (connected to the USB port on the quad) data and streaming this to my PC using netcat. This is all working well and I can see the data coming in on my desktop. I now need a way to listen to this data and convert it into the LaserScan messages that Hector Slam uses.

I am very new to ROS and although have learnt a lot already, I do not know how to do this and can't seem to find any similar posts made here. I may well just be searching for the wrong things but any help would be greatly appreciated!

Cheers,
Andy

PC - Ubuntu 14.04
AR Drone - BusyBox I think

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/229144/convert-network-lidar-data-to-laserscan/) by [andythepandy93](https://answers.ros.org/users/26285/andythepandy93/) on ROS Answers with karma: 55 on 2016-03-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Well, you would need to write a driver listening to the network stream and publishing the lidar data as a `LaserScan` message.

Basically,  this is a simple program (ROS node), that reads this data, puts it in a member of the type `sensor_msgs::LaserScan`, publishes this data, and this is it.

Check out [this question here](http://answers.ros.org/question/10191/documentation-on-writing-hardware-drivers/) about writing hardware drivers....

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2016-03-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [andythepandy93](https://answers.ros.org/users/26285/andythepandy93/) on 2016-03-16**:
Great, thanks for the info. Will give that a read

**Comment by [andythepandy93](https://answers.ros.org/users/26285/andythepandy93/) on 2016-03-16**:
Is there a way to listen to stdin in ROS or somehow otherwise pipe into a node, so that I can let netcat deal with receiving the data and just let the node convert it into the LaserScan format?